# Infinite loop after passing hooks as props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

Im having an infinite loop error after passing hooks as props. In definitive, i want a modal to open after another one is closed.

First of all, im passing up data from GrandChild to ParentComponent successfully. But when it comes to pass data from Parent to ModalComponent (via isOpen hooks), it then trigger an infinite loop and i can't find why.

```
const ParentComponent => {
   const [ isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

   const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setIsOpen(newValue)
  }

return (
  <>
   <ChildComponent handleChange={handleChange} button={<RedPlusLogo />}/>
   <ConfirmationModal isOpen={isOpen} />
  </>
)
}
```

```
const ChildComponent = (props)=> {

 <GrandChildComponent handleChange={props.handleChange} />

}
```

```
const GrandChildComponent = (props) => {
 const handleSubmit = () => {
  props.handleChange(true)
 }
}
```

```
const ConfirmationModal = () => {
 const {isOpen} = props;
 const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

 if (isOpen) {
   setOpen(true)
 }

return (
    <div>
      
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      >
        {body}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You should remove state from ConfirmationModal and just use props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of your logic within `ConfirmationModal` component. the `setOpen` hook runs on each rerender and since changing state of `useState` causes a rerender by itself, then you get infinite loop.

Just utilize `useEffect` to properly handle this.

```
const ConfirmationModal = () => {
 const {isOpen} = props;
 const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
     setOpen(true)
   }
 }, [ isOpen ]);

return (
    <div>
      
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      >
        {body}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const ConfirmationModal = () => {
 const {isOpen} = props;
 const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

 if (isOpen) {
   setOpen(true)
 }

return (
    <div>
      
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="simple-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="simple-modal-description"
      >
        {body}
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Aside of the fact that 'duplicating' state like this is probably unnecessary (why won't you just use `props.isOpen`, instead of copying it into an additional `useState`?), calling `setState` (which causes a rerender) inside the render-phase leads to infinite rerenders.

Change this:

```
 const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

 if (isOpen) {
   setOpen(true)
 }
```

To this:

```
 const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

 React.useEffect(() => isOpen && setOpen(true), [isOpen]);
```